# In Rebol How to get the Object Path Name (String)?

Tags: rebol

Let's say I have

```
list: [system/history system/prompt]
```

I want to convert to

```
list-string: ["system/history" "system/prompt"]
```

This may be an obvious answer but I can't see any :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
>> list: [system/history system/prompt]
>> map-each v list [form v]
== ["system/history" "system/prompt"]
```

Comment: +1 that's [parsimonious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parsimonious).  *(In a good way.)*

Answer (score 1):

There's many simple ways to do this in Rebol. It's interesting to use parse:

```
>> list: [system/history system/prompt]
== [system/history system/prompt]
>> parse list [(list-string: copy []) some [set path path! (append list-string mold path)]]                                                                    
== true
>> list-string                                                                  
== ["system/history" "system/prompt"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, that updates the existing **list** block:

```
list: [system/history system/prompt]
== [system/history system/prompt]

forall list [list/1: mold list/1]

probe list
== ["system/history" "system/prompt"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you never have spaces in the original list (as is true in your example)

```
parse form list none
== ["system/history" "system/prompt"]
```